# Storing Number in an integer from sql Database

Tags: c#

i am using database with table RESUME and column PageIndex in it which type is number in database but when i want to store this PageIndex value to an integer i get exception error

**Specified cast is not valid.**

here is the code

```
string sql;
string conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=D:\\Deliverable4.accdb";
protected OleDbConnection rMSConnection;
protected OleDbDataAdapter rMSDataAdapter;
protected DataSet dataSet;
protected DataTable dataTable;
protected DataRow dataRow;
```

on Button Click

```
sql = "select PageIndex from RESUME";
rMSConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
rMSDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, rMSConnection);
dataSet = new DataSet("pInDex");
rMSDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "RESUME");

dataTable = dataSet.Tables["RESUME"];
```

> int pIndex =
>   (int)dataTable.Rows[0][0];

```
rMSConnection.Close();

if (pIndex == 0)
{            
    Response.Redirect("Create Resume-1.aspx");
}
else if (pIndex == 1)
{            
    Response.Redirect("Create Resume-2.aspx");
}
else if (pIndex == 2)
{          
        Response.Redirect("Create Resume-3.aspx");
    }
}
```

i am getting error in this line

```
int pIndex = (int)dataTable.Rows[0][0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I very humbly suggest a different way of doing this?:

```
string conString = "...";  // <-- your connection string

using (IDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conString))
{   // ^^^ interface type makes your code less dependent on a particular backend!
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        using (IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {   // ^^^ ditto
            command.CommandText = "SELECT PageIndex FROM RESUME";
            object scalar = command.ExecuteScalar();
            // ^ ExecuteScalar reads the first value in the first column
            //   of the result set; or returns null if it fails to do so.

            if (scalar == null) throw ...;  // unexpected result from database!
            if (scalar == DBNull.Value) throw ...;  // ditto!?

            int pIndex = (int)scalar;

            switch (pIndex)
            {
                case 0:  Response.Redirect("Create Resume-1.aspx"); break;
                case 1:  Response.Redirect("Create Resume-2.aspx"); break;
                case 2:  Response.Redirect("Create Resume-3.aspx"); break;
                default: throw ...;  // unexpected result from database!?
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();  // (will execute even when exceptions are thrown!)
    }
}
```

Comment: A null database value will produce `DBNull.Value`, not `null`.

Comment: *@Adam Robinson:* Correct (I added this case), but note that `null` can still occur if there *isn't* a first column of a first row, ie. when the returned result set is completely empty.

Answer (score 2):

If it can't cast it to an integer, then it isn't retrieving it as one from the database. What is the data type of the field?

Try examining the results of `dataTable.Rows[0][0].GetType().ToString()` to see what the object actually is.

Answer (score 2):

You say "type is number in database" - it *sounds* as though this might be `numeric`, in which case the most appropriate match in .NET-land is `decimal`. If you know it is an int, you can simply cast it from `decimal` to `int` afterwards:

```
int pIndex = (int)(decimal)dataTable.Rows[0][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

```
int pIndex = int.Parse(dataTable.Rows[0][0].ToString());
```